# HTML5 Web Storage Creating Variables

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, html, local-storage

I'm looking to create quite a few variables in JavaScript for storing boolean variables in HTML5 Web Storage. I want the variables to be as follows:

```
localStorage.title1 = '0';
localStorage.title2 = '0';
localStorage.title3 = '0';
```

And so on ...

The problem I face is that I want to create these variables all the way to `localStorage.title570`.

I have tried the following code, of which I was suspect to it's failure:

```
function registerUser() {
    for(i=1;i<571;i++)
    {
        var a = "title" + i;
        localStorage.a = 0;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't appear to work. I'm looking for an easy way to create these 570 variables in order to track progress of a user. I have looked at PHP and MySQL but I feel this will hopefully prove slightly more easy. However, if not, I shall simply use PHP and MySQL.

Comment: `localStorage[a] = 0`. Though a JSON-stringified array might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like this instead:

```
for(i=1;i<571;i++)
{
    localStorage['title' + i] = 0;
}
```

or better:

```
for(i=1;i<571;i++){
    localStorage.setItem('title' + i,  '0');
}
```

Comment: Had used `localStorage['title'][String(i)] = 0;` to keep thing somewhat more readable. However, having some trouble showing this in a `div` as I can't seem to check if `localStorage.registered` is set. This just makes sure the user has visited before and if so loads their progress.

Comment: @user2195574 just be aware of that `localStorage` can only store *strings* so all arrays (1D, 2D, ...) and objects need to be "stringified" first (`JSON.stringify`) and when read parsed back to object (`JSON.parse`). Using `localStorage[][]` assumes the first [] to be an array which it isn't with `localStorage` and therefor won't work.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different solution would be to use an array instead of indexing the variable names.
So...

```
function registerUser() {
   localStorage.title=[];     
   for(i=0;i<570;i++)
   {        
      localStorage.title.push(0);
   }
}
```

Or if you didnt need to initiaise the values to 0 then it would just be.

```
function registerUser() {
   localStorage.title=[];            
}
```

Note that now the index starts at 0 instead of 1.